# LangChain vectorStore: how to use search_kwargs filter?

Tags: langchain, chromadb, vector-database

I am following various tutorials on LangChain, and am now trying to figure out how to use a subset of the documents in the vectorstore instead of the whole database.

```
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=splits, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings())
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()
```

Imagine a chat scenario.

- User: I am looking for X.
- Chatbot: (asks a deterministic question e.g.) From what date is this document?
- User: 2023-11-16
  *backend* Filters the vectorstore somehow e.g. `retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(filters="document_name matches '2023-11-16*'")`
- Chatbot: here are some relevant documents: ...

In the documentation, they list an example:

```
docsearch.as_retriever(
    search_kwargs={'filter': {'paper_title':'GPT-4 Technical Report'}}
)
```

What isn't clear is:

- What is paper_title? Is that metadata or text inside the document?
- If this is metadata, then how to specify it?

Answer (score 2):

> What is paper_title? Is that metadata or text inside the document?

`paper_title` is a column name in a document. you are searching through document filtering `'paper_title':'GPT-4 Technical Report'`

`chromadb` uses sqlite to store all the embeddings. [you can read here](https://docs.trychroma.com/troubleshooting)

> If this is metadata, then how to specify it?

yes that is metadata and [from docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/retrievers/self_query) this si how you specify

```
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.schema import Document
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

docs = [
    Document(
        page_content="A bunch of scientists bring back dinosaurs and mayhem breaks loose",
        metadata={"year": 1993, "rating": 7.7, "genre": "science fiction"},
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="Leo DiCaprio gets lost in a dream within a dream within a dream within a ...",
        metadata={"year": 2010, "director": "Christopher Nolan", "rating": 8.2},
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="A psychologist / detective gets lost in a series of dreams within dreams within dreams and Inception reused the idea",
        metadata={"year": 2006, "director": "Satoshi Kon", "rating": 8.6},
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="A bunch of normal-sized women are supremely wholesome and some men pine after them",
        metadata={"year": 2019, "director": "Greta Gerwig", "rating": 8.3},
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="Toys come alive and have a blast doing so",
        metadata={"year": 1995, "genre": "animated"},
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="Three men walk into the Zone, three men walk out of the Zone",
        metadata={
            "year": 1979,
            "director": "Andrei Tarkovsky",
            "genre": "thriller",
            "rating": 9.9,
        },
    ),
]
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(docs, OpenAIEmbeddings())
```

Comment: I thought Chroma DB was a pure vector store -- how are columns added to it? Thanks!

Comment: chroma uses sqlite to store all the documents. https://docs.trychroma.com/troubleshooting